# React Ant Design - How to set Table to 100% height

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, antd

How can I resize and expand the React Ant Design Table to 100% height when the parent container or the browser window are resized too?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-ant-design-table-set-100-height-8lkdg

Answer (score 4):

Set `minHeight` to **ant-table-body**

```
.ant-table-body {
  min-height: 500px;
}
```

Refer to the scroll zone

```
<Table
  scroll={{ y: 500, x: 500 }}
...
```

[image]

Comment: Any ways to fix with %, there are problems different screen size